# Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 8, size is 8

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

So, I have 2 Lists, one characters and one players.

I should get the same index from both and call'em together (Display their values)

But when I do so through a for loop, I get the `Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 8, size is 8` error

Any ideas?

Comment: When you use size you should use size-1 since 4 elements array would have size of 4 therefore when u use a loop it is from 0 to 3.

Comment: The stack trace gives you a line number.  Examine that line carefully.

Comment: @FET - what does your `addCharacter` method look like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was all caused by the way I used to pass the amounts of the players: some values passed even if they were null! So that was causing the list to not fill properly!

Always check that :P Thank everybody anyway for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In almost all programming languages, arrays, strings, and other objects with indices start at zero, and end at `length - 1`. So, an array of size 8 has a maximum index of 7. Check your `characters` object and make sure that it has the same length as `players`.

Comment: It looks like there are 9 players but 8 characters, I think there's an error caused by the method I used to pass the values of the characters.. Gonna update my question right away!